# When saving, I'm not getting all the Photoshop image formats as options

Tags: adobe-photoshop, save, file-format

So I've edited a photo in Photoshop and I try to save it as a JPEG, only it doesn’t give me all the options for formats; no PNG or anything. Why is this?

Anyone have any suggestions or know any possible fix for this?

[image]

Comment: Not sure if I understand, but there is the "save as" option, and the "export" option. Those should cover it?

Comment: Is your file over 2GB in size?

Comment: JPG doesn't support layers. you need to uncheck the Layers box.

Answer (score 17):

If you’re using a version of Photoshop earlier than CS6 and your document is 16-bit, or if it is in a color mode such as Lab or multichannel that isn’t supported in JPEG format, then JPEG won’t be offered as an option on save.

- *Image → Mode → RGB Color*
- *Image → Mode → 8 Bits/Channel*

Then *Save As.*

One of the much-welcomed features in CS6 (or maybe CS5 – I forget), was that 16-bit images could be saved directly to jpeg, with Photoshop doing the conversion to 8-bit on the fly, but that still means that if your document’s color space isn’t available in JPEG, then Photoshop won’t offer JPEG as an option when saving.

Answer (score 5):

You file is probably too large. I had the same problem: the resolution was over 25000×30000. Reduce the file’s dimensions, then you can save in JPEG.

Comment: I'm still not sure why this limitation exists in Photoshop when I have seen JPG files much larger than those dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

For me in Photoshop CS6, I had JPEG available, but no PNG.  The issue for me is that PNG format does not support the CMYK color mode.  The solution was to change to the RGB color mode via:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the document is in CMYK mode, it will not allow you to export as PNG.
Convert it to RGB and that should fix it

Answer (score 0):

Please change the image bit to 16 or 8, if you are using 32bit, it will never allow you to save as a JPEG or PNG images,

Answer (score 0):

**Three very likely fixes :**

1. Wrong color mode or bit settings (8, 16 or 24 bit image) : PNG, for example, can only be saved if the image is in RGB mode.
2. File size : if your file is huge, you'll have to save it as a PDF, EPS or PSD large-psd file.
3. Your preferences need to be reset. I just bumped against photoshop not offering me JPEG or PNG, and resetting the preferences through the preferences menu did it. In my psd version, it was a checkbox saying 'Reset preferences next time Photoshop quits.'

Answer (score -1):

i had the same problem..
nothing worked.. if plugins & version are fine
do this- (based on CS3 version)
on near right corner of Photoshop screen find a drop down that says 'workspace' - from it select "default work-space"

create a new file and try saving it

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Change the resolution when you create new photo.
Select *pixels* as units for height and width.

When you create a new image use this as a default. *File → New* with: 450 pixels, height: 450 pixels, resolution: 72 pixel/inch, color mode: RGB color 8 bit

Comment: I did, I still don't understand how this answers the question or adds anything beyond what Alan Gilbertson's answer has already tackled.