# There is no any options when saving

Tags: adobe-photoshop

So I've edited a photo in Photoshop and I try to save it, but it doesn't give me any the options for formats; no .png or anything. Why is this?

Anyone have any suggestions or know any possible fix for this?

Screenshot: 
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Try clicking that arrow in the bottom left corner. Not familiar with the language but I think it probably says 'More Options' or something of that nature.

Comment: It says 'Hide Folders'

Comment: Ah, got it. Obviously not the right answer ;)

Comment: Possibly related/dupe: [When saving, I'm not getting all the Photoshop image formats as options](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/28547/30985)

Answer (score 1):

If you go **File > Save**, Photoshop will save your file with inherited format (.PSD if I look at your screenshot).

Go **File > Save as** in order to pick up the desired format in the dropdown list

Or **File > Save for Web** if you want an optimized picture for web purposes

[image]

Comment: It still looks like i posted before.