# I cant save a fully transparent image

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image: here is my problem]

please help, i cant save a fully transparent image

Comment: So infuriating and patronizing when designers try to force your hand with these "anti-features". It probably took extra work to remove the ability to save a uniform rgba(0,0,0,0) pixel image than it would have been to simply let the user decide what they should and shouldn't do themselves.

Answer (score 3):

If you try to Export then with no coloured pixels at all, or even with an entirely transparent mask, Photoshop will claim the image is empty - which, strictly speaking, it is.

However, if you Save as… then it will allow you to save a completely empty image.

Comment: ok i did that but the image saved is now white instead of transparent ....

Comment: Then save it in a format that can use transparency/alpha… ie png, **not** jpg.

Comment: hi sorry but i am not seeing any png option :(

Comment: https://ibb.co/KmbW1sx

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea why that is. I don't use Windows (which I think is what that looks like) This is what the save dialog looks like on Mac, with a drop menu of format types… https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4DDs.png

Comment: could you tell me what color mode you are using ?

Comment: RGB8-bit, though same applies for 16-bit. png can't save CMYK, you'd need tiff, but your posted screenshot shows RGB

Comment: @farcry possibly related: [when saving, I'm not getting all the Photoshop image formats as options](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/28547/30985)

Answer (score 2):

File -> Export -> Save for Web (Legacy) will let you export a blank transparent png.

Comment: So will File > Save As...